# Flat representations: trying to understand Wiles' proof

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Trying to understand the proof of Fermat's last theorem, can anyone explain to me how exactly a finite flat group scheme over $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ gives rise to a Galois representation over a finite field?

Comment: Look at the generic fiber.  There is a finite extension $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ such that base change yields a constant group over $K$ with a descent datum.  If this constant group scheme is isomorphic to a vector space over a finite field $F$, then the descent datum may yield an $F$-linear Galois action.

Comment: From this and your previous question, I make the guess that you are trying to read through Wiles' paper lacking some basic knowledge. I would suggest that you read parallely Saito's books on Fermat's Last Theorem, which contains a very large part of the proof and much of the background needed to understand it.